# Constantly getting an error: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, cmake, gtk

I'm working on a project that consists of a number of .c files. Therefore, to simplify things I'm using cmake to build files. The following code is in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES
        utils.c
        importLXCat.c
        monte_carlo.c
        object.c
        vector.c
        errors.c
        scalar.c
        d2_matrix.c
        mt19937ar.c
        randn.c)

link_libraries(m)

add_library(methes_core ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Then, in the terminal I build the cake using `cmake -H. -Bbuild`. Everything is fine till now.

In the next step, when I complete building using `cmake --build build -- -j3`, I get the error: `gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory.`

I've used  `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` in a couple of C files in my project.

It'd be great if someone can help me.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30493596/1971013) help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add compiler arguments using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514291/how-to-add-compiler-arguments-using-cmake)

Answer (score 0):

You should link your program to GTK.

1) Look for gtk using: [`find_package(GTK REQUIRED)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGTK.html)

2) Since GTK seems not a Modern CMake target, then use:

```
target_include_directories(methes_core PRIVATE ${GTK_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(methes_core PRIVATE ${GTK_LIBRARIES})
```

note: Hope In the future, we can only do `target_link_libraries(methes_core PRIVATE gtk::gtk)` for step 2...