# QtCreator is not executing pkg-confing with cmake

Tags: cmake, qt-creator, pkg-config

I have simple project in QtCreator with cmake which uses gtk. So i set compiler flags to this :-

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -std=c++14 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`")

but it does not compile and gives me following output:-

[Errors screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8txu.png)

```
:-1: error: error: `pkg-config: No such file or directory
:-1: error: error: gtk+-3.0`: No such file or directory
:-1: error: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--cflags’
:-1: error: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--libs’
```

here is my cmake file:-

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(untitled1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -std=c++14 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`")


FIND_PACKAGE(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake and pkg-config (juCi++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634710/cmake-and-pkg-config-juci)

Comment: Also related in terms of question content: [How to add compiler arguments using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514291/how-to-add-compiler-arguments-using-cmake)